# Use CSS transforms or javascript to scale an element to fit its parent dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a page in which I have a wheel of `<div>` elements, the entire wheel rotates when you click a button.

I achieve this effect by using CSS transforms, which are absolute in nature. However the wheel is very big, it looks nice on my HD display, but smaller screens get the edges cut off. I can not use % widths like I could with a normal layout, what I need is to scale the entire page down in the same way most browsers zoom functions work.

For myself I know that ctr+mouseWheel will zoom out the page so I can see the entire page, however I can not expect others to do this.

I know I can use `-browser-transform: scale(amt);` on a wrapper div to get the effect I want, however I can not figure out a way to do it dynamically. If I set the scale to .5 it will be .5, no matter the screen. I want the edges of the wheel to just be a few pixels from the edges of the screen on ANY screen. I know that media queries could be used to help the problem, but they would either leave me with results that are less than ideal, or require too many different queries. There must be a way to modify `-browser-transform: scale(amt);` programmatically, or some other way to have finite control.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, I got tumbleweed on this one. Nobody got a clue?

Comment: Do you have absolute sizes for (parts of) the wheel? It helps if you add a small + working example in the question, it's a bit hard to imagine what your code looks like. - In any case, the way I read it, if you have a fixed wheel size and a fixed (but unkown up front) browser size you'll need JavaScript to determine the scale.

Comment: Are you saying you want to calculate `amt` based on the viewport size?

Comment: It seems the most straightforward way to do this would be to use JS to set the style properties on page load once it has the window size. If JS is something you can use for this, drop a comment or update your question; it's fairly easy to do.

Comment: Problem is I can't find the correct way to do this in JS. Because the `-browser-transform: scale(amt);` is proprietary (different for each browser) I can not find the proper way to modify with JS.

Comment: you can use css3 transform2d scale with vendor prefixes to take care of that instead of js by the way.

Comment: Is this roughly the effect you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/UuWrZ/

Comment: The wheel is made up of many div elements arranged using -browser-transform:` CSS. While that JS fiddle works fine for a div shaped like a circle, it is not able to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using media queries in css to target different screens. for example, have a media query in your css file that states that at a width of 320 - 480 pixels, the div containing this wheel is scaled to 50%. Then at 481-768 pixels, the div container is scaled to 75%. and from 769 pixels up, the div is scaled to 100%.

That should help you accomplish the dynamic scaling you want at different screen sizes. If you would like a demo, I'll be glad to make a jsfiddle showing it.

Comment: While it would technically work, I would need many media queries to account for a wide array of screen sizes, while still keeping the appearance within acceptable deviations. And remember that not everyone is viewing with the browser filling the screen, the number of possible sizes is far to large. In short, too much redundancy, media queries are not an elegant solution.

Comment: not necessarily, for example, split-screening a 1920x1080 monitor brings it down to 1920x540, which would be in the range of (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px). If you use ranges, then you don't need that many. First start off with a basic site for a week or so with google analytics, see what resolutions people visit the site with, and design mostly for those. Or if you don't want to wait, design for the most common such as 320x480, 800x480, 960x640, 1024x768, 1600x900, 1920x1080. And don't forget it isn't that much work simulating and writing a new decimal for each screen size.

Comment: I want to make you a jsfiddle doing this for you, do you have sizes in mind other than the ones i listed above in my response and in my comment before yours? And do you have a fiddle with the wheel created already?

Comment: I don't need a proof of concept, I know it will work to a certain extent, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: not for proof of concept, i would like to actually do it for you because I feel that this is the most elegant solution and if you choose not to use it, I'm fine with that. Besides, good opportunity for me to use media queries and css transforms. I'd like to do it for you.